# How can I count files in multiple listbox items

Tags: vb.net

**The purpose...**

How can I read how many files in multiple folders.

So within the program I'm supposed to add and remove folders that I wanna monitor. So I'm adding folders to a listbox. The `listbox` will eventually contain a few items that are paths like `\\server\parent directory\directory`

**The issue**

Now this all works, adding the specified paths as items to the listbox, but now I want to count files in all the folders that are in the listbox and output a number to a textbox.

I've figured out how to do this if I have a textbox that contains a single path;

```
Dim counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(tbchannel1.Text)
    tbCount1.Text = ("" & CStr(counter.Count))
```

But I can't figure out how to twist this around to work with all the items in a listbox instead.

*...And btw, this is going to happen at the press of a button. Eventuelly I'll hook up a timer that button.performclick*

Thanks!

Comment: Do all your folders share the same base path, for example `C:\Users\(Check all folders here)` or are there multiples such as `C:\Users\(Check all folders here)` then the next folder is `C:\Temp\(Check all folders here)`?

Comment: @SilverShotBee They are all in the same parent directory, but different subfolders and also subfolders of subfolders. For example, there can be folders added like `c:\temp\aaa\aaa` then `c:\temp\bbb\bbb` `c:\temp\ccc\ccc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you

```
Private Sub CountFilesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CountFilesButton.Click
    Try
        Dim fileTotal As Integer
        For Each item As String In DirListBox.Items
            fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString).Count
        Next
        FileCountLabel.Text = String.Format("File count: {0}", fileTotal.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

It'll be up to you to validate the path exists and handle other errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andrew. This is exactly what I needed! :)